# Discord.py IF statement not passing?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I feel like this is an easy fix but I can't figure out why I'm getting this response.

I set each `if` statement to have a unique error message so I can see where the error is.

Every time I run `$setbirthday 05/03` in my server I get the `"Invalid month specified!"` while the first index of my argument (**0**) would seemingly pass this.

[image]

Here is the code:

```py
class BirthdayCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot


    @commands.command(pass_context=true)
    async def setbirthday(self, ctx, args):
        user = ctx.author
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Creator")
        if role in user.roles:
            if args != '':
                # If it's an actual month (index 0)
                if args[0] != 0 or args[0] != 1:
                    await ctx.send("Invalid month specified!")
                else:
                    # If it's an actual month (index 1)
                    if args[1] < 0:
                        await ctx.send("That's not a valid month!")
                    elif args[1] <= 9:
                        # If they separated month/day using "/"
                        if args[2] != "/":
                            await ctx.send("You have to specify your birthday like `MM/DD`!")
                        else:
                            # If it's an actual day (index 0)
                            if args[3] > 3:
                                await ctx.send("Invalid day specified!")
                            elif args[3] < 0:
                                await ctx.send("That isn't a day!")
                            else:
                                # If it's an actual day (index 1)
                                if args[4] < 0:
                                    await ctx.send("Incorrect day!")
                                else:
                                    # Make sure there's no extra numbers
                                    if args[5] != '':
                                        await ctx.send("Make sure it's just `MM/DD`!")
                                    else:
                                        birthday = args[0] + '' + args[1] + '' + "/" + args[3] + '' + args[4]
                                        await ctx.send("Your birthday has been registered as: " + "`" + str(birthday) + "`" + "!")
                    else:
                        await ctx.send("Error!")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Set your birthday by doing `$setbirthday MM/DD`")
        else:
            await ctx.send("You don't have the required role to set your birthday!")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main problems in your code :

- You should use guard clauses instead of nesting if statements, it'll make your code easier to read and understand
- You can use `string.split()` instead of having to comment what each index corresponds to, it also simplifies your conditions.

You then obtain this code:

```py
@commands.command()
async def setbirthday(self, ctx, arg):
    user = ctx.author
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Creator")

    if role not in user.roles:
        return await ctx.send("You don't have the required role to set your birthday!")

    if len(arg.split('/')) != 2:
        return await ctx.send("You have to specify your birthday like `MM/DD`!")

    month, day = arg.split("/")

    if not month.isdigit() or not 1 <= int(month) <= 12:
        return await ctx.send("Invalid month specified!")

    if not day.isdigit() or not 1 <= int(day) <= 31:
        return await ctx.send("Invalid day specified!")

    await ctx.send(f"Your birthday has been registered as: {month}/{day}!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things.

- Problem #1: It seems that `args[0]` here would be a string, namely `args[0] = '05/03'`. The args are split by spaces (`args` = the arguments passed by the discord user excluding `$setbirthday`, and split by space). In order to extract the first character, you would need to do `args[0][0]`. Which would lead us to the next problem.
- Problem #2: The `if args[0] != 0 or args[0] != 1:` is circular in essence. The way that the `or` operator works is that it checks `if a is true` OR `if b is true`, then proceed into the if statement. These conditions are independent of one another. Suppose that the input is the integer (number) `1`. Then before your if statement can even get to `or args[0] != 1`, it has already triggered `if args[0] != 0`. After all, `0 != 1` . The correct operator here is `and`.
- Problem #3: As I mentioned in #1, `args[0]` is a string and `args[0][0]` is a character. Your if statement is, in essence, checking if: `'0' != 0`.  they are **indeed not the same**, so the if statement would still activate. You can either convert the character in `args[0][0]` to an integer (`if int(args[0][0]) != 0`) or you can compare `args[0][0]` to the character `'0'`: `(if args[0][0] != '0')`.

To sum all of that up, try this instead:

```
#String/Character Comparison
 if (args[0][0] != '0') and (args[0][0] != '1'):

#Int Comparison
 if (int(args[0][0]) != 0) and (int(args[0][0]) != 1):
```